# Is it possible to set items as available for pickup in Square API?

Tags: php, curl, square-connect

I am creating items using the Square API. In the Square dashboard > item library, in the "online store settings" section, there is "available for pickup" and "available for shipping". Is there a way I can have 'available for pickup' checked by default when I create an item with the API?

I know the documentation says "You cannot currently manage pickup orders with the Connect API." But what I want to do has to do with managing items, not orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When creating an item, set the `available_for_pickup` field to `true` in your request body, like so:

```
{
  "name": "Milkshake",
  "visibility": "PUBLIC",
  "variations": [
    {
      "name": "Small",
      "pricing_type": "FIXED_PRICING",
      "price_money": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "amount": 400
      },
    }
  ],
  "available_for_pickup": true
}
```

A couple of clarifications:

- An item's `visibility` must be set to `PUBLIC` for it to appear in the online store.
- The `available_online` field (not shown in the above example) controls only whether an item can be added to *shipping* orders. You only need to set the `available_for_pickup` and `visibility` fields for pickup-only items.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! One more quick thing, is there a way to get the online store URL for the newly created item through the API?

Comment: Item online store URLs are currently not available through the Connect API.